# With perl CGI print on webpage STDOUT of executed command gradually

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a CGI script in perl that runs swi-prolog with dummy goal:

*it writes "1" then after a second writes "2" on a new line etc in the end writes "end" on a new line*

My aim is to get a web page where *1, 2, 3, end* will be written **gradually** as it happens in terminal if you execute this prolog code.

mwe of perl CGI:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;
use CGI;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

print <<EOF;
<html>
<head><title>Title</title></head>
<body>
EOF

my $out = `swipl -g 'writeln(1), sleep(1), writeln(2), sleep(1), writeln(3), sleep(1),  writeln(end)' -t halt`;
print "<pre>$out</pre>";

print <<EOF;
</body>
</html>
EOF
exit;
```

Comment: You *could* do this by sending four separate pages from the server, but the timing would be very inaccurate. The way to do this is to embed some JavaScript in the page that runs in the browser. Since you're only doing it for curiosity's sake I suggest you find something else

Answer (score 3):

Backticks don't work the way you're hoping.  Perl will spawn the child process & wait for it to complete (`sleep` statements & all).  It's output will then be assigned to `$out` & only then will your script continue, printing the single string `$out` all at once.

Instead you should use a pipe:

```
open my $program_pipe, '-|', 'unbuffer', 'swipl', '-g', q{writeln(1), yada yada}
    or die 'Help me Rhonda';
local $| = 1; # we don't want the web server waiting on us as we wait on the kid.
while (my $line = <$program_pipe>) {
  print $line;
}
```

You will probably want to make sure your child program is flushing output before each `sleep` or you'll get your pauses at unpredictable points, because any buffered output will remain unwritten while the program sleeps.  `unbuffer` creates a pseudo-tty for the child, and this "fools" most programs into performing line buffering instead of block buffering.

For some final polish, you'll probably want to complete the document 1st with some JavaScript that then uses AJAX or web socket like techniques to deliver the additional content...